# XPath concat function not works

Tags: xpath, concatenation

I am trying get the first and second `<td>` in all the `<tr>` from this table with XPath. But something I am doing wrong. Return `[INVALID XPATH EXPRESSION]`

```
//table[@id='thetable']/tbody/tr/concat(td[1],'-',td[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string-join(//table[@id='thetable']/tbody/tr/td[1 to 2]/string(), "-")
```

Comment: Nope. Same result

Comment: @jesusowins What are you using to evaluate the XPath?

Comment: The Chrome DevTools console and XPath Helper Wizard extension for Chrome.

Comment: If you paste in parts of the expression are you able to deduce which part it considers invalid? I suspect its either the functions or the @id equals operator.

Answer (score 1):

Using concat() on the right hand side of "/" requires an XPath 2.0 engine. The error message suggests you are trying to run this using an XPath 1.0 engine. The string-join version also needs XPath 2.0.

In fact any expression that returns a sequence of strings is going to need XPath 2.0 because the XPath 1.0 type system doesn't have any such data type.

If you want an XPath 2.0 implementation that runs in the browser you could try Saxon-JS. (In fact that will give you XPath 3.1).